# How do I remove the selected tag filter when searching for Unanswered questions on Superuser?

Tags: support, tags

I've been looking for unanswered questions trying to build some reputation here. Once I select a tag filter in the sidebar, I'm shown all of the questions with that tag. Choosing more tags makes the filter more specific and choosing one of the tags from the set I've already chosen replaces the whole set with that one tag.

But, how do I remove that lone tag so that I can return to the full list of Unanswered questions?

Comment: Just because there are answers posted, does not mean they are the right ones, you can build your reputation by giving the correct answers even though they are not unanswered. So look at answered questions when the site is slow at night (CST) and there are no new questions being posted. This gives you time to research and give the correct answer which might be accepted the next day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha. You can return to the full, unfiltered list by clicking the "Unanswered" link in the main navigation. Not quite intuitive – I was hoping to click the tag and have it removed – but it works.